# Works in jsfiddle but not on html page

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to figure out what is wrong but i'm being stumped as the code works in jsfiddle but not on my html page any help would greatly be appreciated. What is happening is the clock that shows up and the fancy box for you to input the time are not working.

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E4xP3/8/

but when I run it on my site i get

[image]

I took the advice below and changed my html and it is still broken, I see that people recommend the below but I can no longer generate the csv http://jsfiddle.net/KUDut/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

What should be generating is the stuff in  and it clearly is working some what as the value 06:00 PM is showing up.

```
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
<input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="timepicker" value="06:00 PM"/>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
```

The html code as follows

```
<html>
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
<input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="timepicker" value="06:00 PM"/>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
<input id="timepicker2" type="text" class="timepicker" value="06:00 PM"/>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>
<button id="submit">Generate CSV Time</button>
<br/>
<textarea id="csvContent" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="CSV content will go here">
</textarea> 

<script>    
$(function() {
$( "#timepicker1" ).timepicker();
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#timepicker2" ).timepicker();
});
</script>  

</body>   

<script type="text/javascript">



$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
defaultTime: 'current',
minuteStep: 1,
disableFocus: true,
template: 'dropdown'
});

$('#timepicker2').timepicker({
defaultTime: 'current',
minuteStep: 1,
disableFocus: true,
template: 'dropdown'
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
    var csv = '';
    var curtime = '';
    $('.timepicker').each(function() {
            csv += curtime = $(this).data('timepicker').getTime();      

            csv += ',' + "\n";
    });
    csv = csv.substr(0, csv.length-2); 
    $('#csvContent').text(csv);
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After changing http://imgur.com/325ahbD

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have `<body>` tag and you're missing `<script>` tag around your jQuery code at the end.

Comment: I forgot to add them in my post but i corrected it but im still having issues.

Comment: You need to place your `<script>` at the end before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: I changed it all around again but still a no go :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing link type =   to   link rel="stylesheet" help me far much than i would like to admit and I dont really understand why.

The only thing now is that the time box is too small and the pop out where you can select the times are only big enough to display half of what is needed https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx19T.jpg

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code should be in script tag.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#timepicker1').timepicker({
    defaultTime: 'current',
    minuteStep: 1,
    disableFocus: true,
    template: 'dropdown'
    });

    $('#timepicker2').timepicker({
    defaultTime: 'current',
    minuteStep: 1,
    disableFocus: true,
    template: 'dropdown'
    });

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var csv = '';
        var curtime = '';
        $('.timepicker').each(function() {
                csv += curtime = $(this).data('timepicker').getTime()      

                csv += ',' + "\n";
        });
        csv = csv.substr(0, csv.length-2); 
        $('#csvContent').text(csv);
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I accidentally did forgot to add them and edited the html, but it still does not work.

Comment: I over look that to quickly let me try out the rest

Comment: I did add the $(document).ready(function(){ but after I do i still dont get the clock and i can no longer generate the csv http://jsfiddle.net/KUDut/

Comment: I've updated your code. Your just missing some semicolons. http://jsfiddle.net/KUDut/7/